# Does `readonly` in C# also make the same distinction between variables of value types and reference types as `final` in Java?

Tags: java, c#

In Java,

- a variable of a reference type modified by `final` cannot be changed to refer to any other object
- a variable of a primitive type modified by `final` cannot be changed to have a different value

I asked that at [Does `final` means a field is not mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893757)

Does `readonly` in C# also make the same distinction between variables of value types and reference types?

Thanks.

Comment: `final` does not make any distinction between reference or primitive type values. It works the same for both types of values in Java. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I just added a link to my similar Java question

Comment: Method invocation and field access don't change just because they're used on a value that happens to come from a `final` variable. Those features are unrelated to `final`.

Answer (score 3):

When used as a modifier to a variable the `readonly` in C# is the equivalent of Java’s `final` therefore they behave exactly the same way for both value types and reference types in their respective languages.

## Java's "Final" Behaviour

You can only initialize a final variable once and only once. This has nothing to do with whether an objects state can be modified or not.

## C# "readonly" Behaviour

The `readonly` keyword is a modifier that you can only use on fields. Given a variable that is declared with a `readonly` modifier, any assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

The `Readonly` modifier prevents fields from being changed. Therefore any attempt to change them later are disallowed.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a link to my similar Java question. Hope that you will understand what I ask for C#.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the last sentence in your reply, what kinds of variables can `readonly` and `final` apply to respectively?

Comment: regarding local variables, in java you can use the “final” modifier with any type of variable you wish but in C# this not even a valid syntax when using “readonly” as a modifier to local variables.

Comment: What can `final` apply to? local variables of methods, fields of classes, ...? What can `readonly` apply to? only fields of classes?

Comment: “final” can be used to prevent classes from being inherited, it can be used to prevent methods from being overridden, it can prevent all types of variables from being reassigned after being assigned the first time. The “readonly” modifier is only used for fields in C#.

Comment: I cannot find a single sentence in this answer that is actually true.

Comment: @Aominè `readonly` has special behavior for value types; see my answer.  "It must be initialised latest by the end of each constructor and after that it can no longer be reassigned" is false: a `readonly` field may be assigned never, once, or more than once, as long as all assignments occur inline or in a constructor.  A `final` field must be assigned _exactly once_.  "The only distinction..." false, as per the differences mentioned.

Comment: @MikeStrobel see edit, I have updated the answer to be more specific.

Comment: @Aominè Much better :).

Answer (score 1):

> In Java,
>
> - a variable of a reference type modified by final cannot be changed to refer to any other object
> - a variable of a primitive type modified by final cannot be changed to have a different value
>
> Does readonly in C# also make the same distinction between variables of value types and reference types?

That is mostly the case, yes.  Neither `final` nor `readonly` fields may be modified after you leave a constructor: a reference type field may not be assigned to point to a different object, and a value type field may not be assigned a different value.  But that's not the whole story.

While Java's `final` and C#'s `readonly` modifiers largely serve the same purpose, there are some differences you should be aware of.

### Assignment Rules

A `final` field in Java must be assigned *exactly once*, either with an inline field initializer, or by assignment in each constructor<sup>[1]</sup>.  A `readonly` field in C# can only be initialized inline or in a constructor, but there are no restrictions on how many times it may be assigned; it may be assigned once, more than once, or never.

### Value Types and Mutability

There is a subtle behavioral difference between `readonly` fields of value types versus reference types.  When a value type field is marked `readonly`, any access to that field results in a copy being made.  This prevents you from performing any potentially mutating operations on the field itself, effectively rendering it *internally immutable*.  For example:

```
struct TestStruct { 
    public int Count;
    public int Increment() { return ++Count; }
}

class MutableTest { 
    TestStruct s;
    public void Test() { 
        Console.WriteLine(s.Increment());
    }
}

class ImmutableTest { 
    readonly TestStruct s;
    public void Test() { 
        Console.WriteLine(s.Increment());
    }
}
```

If you declare a `MutableTest` and invoke `Test()` twice, you will see it print `1` and then `2`.  Do the same with an `ImmutableTest` instance, and you will see `1` and then `1` again.

Note, however, that Java has no notion of user-defined value types: all value types in Java are immutable primitives, so declaring a primitive field as `final` does not and could not affect "internal" mutability in this way.

Neither modifier affects the internal mutability of reference types, e.g., adding a `final` or `readonly` modifier will not, on its own, prevent you from modifying the target object's fields or properties, nor will it prevent you from calling methods that may mutate the object.

### Compile-Time Constants

Unlike `readonly`, the `final` modifier may be combined with `static` to define a compile-time constant.  If a `static final` field has a primitive or `String` value, and its inline initializer is a compile-time constant expression, then the compiler may replace any references to it with the underlying constant value.  In such cases, the field will not actually be read.  The same can be achieved in C# with the `const` keyword; it cannot be done with `readonly`.

### Modification by Reflection

It is worth noting that a `readonly` field may be modified through reflection.  This effectively bypasses the requirement that `readonly` fields be assigned only during object construction.  The same is not true in Java: any attempt to reflectively modify a `final` field will trigger an exception.

### Local Variables and Formal Parameters

Lastly, in Java, formal method parameters and local variables may be marked as `final`.  This is strictly a language-level feature, and it has no impact on the generated bytecode<sup>[2]</sup>.  A `final` variable, like a field, must be assigned exactly once.  C# has no equivalent to `readonly` or `final` for local variables or formal parameters.

---

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> Alternatively, a `final` field could be assigned once in an *instance initializer* block.  However, these are seldom used, and the use of an instance initializer is equivalent to prepending the block's contents to the beginning of each instance constructor.</sub>

<sub><sup>[2]</sup> Technically, in some cases a formal parameter's `final` designation may be recorded in a metadata table, but the bytecode within the method body is unaffected.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` makes no distinction between reference types or value types. `readonly` simply means that the *value* stored in a variable can not be changed outside a field initializer or a constructor.

What makes you think it’s necessary to differentiate between value and reference types? Variables are placeholder of *values*, regardless their type. *What* that value is or represents is another story.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a link to my similar Java question. Hope that you will understand what I ask for C#.